# How to restore greeter settings changes made in Ubuntu Tweak?

Tags: 15.04, lightdm, default, ubuntu-tweak, unity-greeter

I was playing around with "Ubuntu Tweak" and changed some of the greeter settings. Now I would like to restore these to their defaults.
Is there a way to undo all changes made by Ubuntu Tweak?

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 desktop edition.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get purge lightdm` and then `sudo apt-get install lightdm` before rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Ubuntu Tweak source it writes two configuration files, `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/50_unity-greeter.gschema.override` and `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. The first file contains settings for the GUI (Unity Greeter) and the second the setting for disabling guest login. Both of these files can be safely removed for correct operation of both LightDM and Unity Greeter (requires root access to delete).

Comment: I can't test this because I am not on Ubuntu anymore. However I will keep this in mind when I reinstall Ubuntu later on. Thank you.